# Ushahidi No Input File Specified

Tags: file, input

I have been trying to install Ushahidi platform for weeks but without any luck. I recently started over using Ushahidi latest release **ushahidi-Ushahidi_Web-2.0.1-140-g0991172.zip** and extracted it to folder ushahidi under my root.

I am using godaddy Linux server. I have tried both the manual and wizard to setup Ushahidi. In all cases, after installation, I get the same error when I try to access admin page. The error reads:

**No input file specified.**

I have tried tried installing using the wizard and the manual process. My PHP version is as required.

Any help will be appreciated. I need it to work so I can move on and customize it. Very disappointing such a good open source tool has poor installation guides!

Thanks.
Sting

Answer (score 1):

there are a few things that can trip up following the installation.

Make sure that:

- mod_rewrite is turned on in apache "a2enmod rewrite"
- AllowOverride All is set in your apache config for your site (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default)
- your .htaccess file points to the correct webroot